# grep-bash command w/ regular expressions coming back with 0 results,looking for alternatives

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to write to write something in linux bash to export a pattern along with the header with helpful information. For instance if my source file im reading looks like:

> test1
>   LKJHJKLKJJJKLKHJKLKJHJKLKJHJKLLKJHJHJKKLKJKLKJHHHJJKLLKLKKJHJKLKJHKJHJKJHJKLKJHKJHJKJHJKJHJKJHJKJHJKJHKKJHJKLKJHJKJHJKJHJKJKJJHHHHHJJJJJKKKKKKK
>
> test2
>   KJKJKJKJKLJJKJJKLLLKKJJKLJJHJKKKKHKHKHJJHJKKJKKLKKJHJKKKLKJHJKKKJHJKLLKJJHJJKJJHJKKLJJHJKLJJJKKKKLLKJJHJKLLJJHJKLLJJHJKLLKJHJHKKLLKKJJHJHKKLLKJJHJJKLLKKJJJKKKKJKKJJKLLK
>
> test3
>   KJHKKJKLKJJKKKKJJHJLKLKJJHHKLJHJKLHLHLHLJLKJHHKLKJHLKJHKLLJHJHKLKJJHKLLKJHJKLLKJHHKKLLKKKKKLKJHHKLLJJHHKKLLKJHJKLJJHHKLKJHJLJJKLKLJHJKKLLLJJKLLKJKLJJJLKJHJHJKKLLKJJHKLJHKLLJHHKKLKJHKKLKJJHJKLLJHHKKLLJJHJHKLJJKKHJ
>
> test4
>   LKJKLLLKJHKLKLJLJKJJLKJKKHKHKHLJLHHLKLJKLHLJLKHLKJLHLHLHLKJHLKHLKHLKJLJLHLKJLJLHLJKLKHLJHJLHLHJLKJJLKHLKHLKHLKHLKJJLJLJLHLKLKJLJLLHJKHLKHLHLJHLJHLJHLJHLHLJLKJLKJLJHHJHKJHKJHKJHKKHKHKHJLJLLJLJHKHKJHKJHKJHKJHKJHJLJLJLHLJHLKLKHLKHKLKLKHKKHLKHLHH

[Picture of my data input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j6u9.png)

and my pattern string is KKHKHKH

I want to return: 
    test2
    KJKJKJKJKLJJKJJKLLLKKJJKLJJHJKKKKHKHKH

> test4 LKJKLLLKJHKLKLJLJKJJLKJLJLHHLKLJKLHLJLKHLKJLHLHLHLKJHLKHLKHLKJLJLHLKJLJLHLJKLKHLJHJLHLHJLKJJLKHLKHLKHLKHLKJJLJLJLHLKLKJLJLLHJKHLKHLHLJHLJHLJHLJHLHLJLKJLKJLJHHJHKJHKJHKJHKKHKHKH

The key is to end at the pattern, instead of the following test. There might also be duplicates in the sequence. I want to write to the furthest match  under each test header (Example in test 4)

We have learned about grep in class, so I used grep with extended regular expressions -E or egrep to try and solve the problem. I know in some forums people have tried sed.

I have tried running this with
grep -E 'test|KKHKHKH' file.txt

grep -E '>test\d+\n[LKJH]*KKHKHKH' file.txt
I ran it through debugger again and this time my expression was wrong, I think I messed up the formatting somehow, but it was working before :(. Just doesn't work in bash

I expected again the output to be:

```
test2  
KJKJKJKJKLJJKJJKLLLKKJJKLJJHJKKKKHKHKH
```

> test4
>   LKJKLLLKJHKLKLJLJKJJLKJLJLHHLKLJKLHLJLKHLKJLHLHLHLKJHLKHLKHLKJLJLHLKJLJLHLJKLKHLJHJLHLHJLKJJLKHLKHLKHLKHLKJJLJLJLHLKLKJLJLLHJKHLKHLHLJHLJHLJHLJHLHLJLKJLKJLJHHJHKJHKJHKJHKKHKHKH

but for the first expression grep -E 'test|KKHKHKH' file.txt I get:

```
test1
test2
KJKJKJKJKLJJKJJKLLLKKJJKLJJHJKKKKHKHKH
test3
test4
```

> LKJKLLLKJHKLKLJLJKJJLKJLJLHHLKLJKLHLJLKHLKJLHLHLHLKJHLKHLKHLKJLJLHLKJLJLHLJKLKHLJHJLHLHJLKJJLKHLKHLKHLKHLKJJLJLJLHLKLKJLJLLHJKHLKHLHLJHLJHLJHLJHLHLJLKJLKJLJHHJHKJHKJHKJHKKHKHKH

I need to somehow only get test2 and test 4 back I guess I could pipe it again through grep, but not sure how I would get the headers with it. I was thinking I could use -B and count the lines previous. But each sequence could be slightly larger.

for the last expression I get nothing returned, though it appeared to work in regex101 debugger at least at one point... :(

If there is no easy grep expression, is there a bash script that I could try?

Comment: I was trying to figure that out as technically the code began with >, I see what I can do thanks!

Comment: `grep` doesn't generally support Perl escapes like `\d` and `\n`.

Comment: This might help with GNU grep: `grep -Poz '\n?test\d+\n.*KKHKHKH' file`

Comment: pops up blinking cursor,and freezes. But thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` examines a single line of input at a time. Thus a regex which needs to straddle a newline character will never match (never mind then that `\n` doesn't mean newline in the regex dialect supported by `grep`). You want something like

```
awk '/^test/ { t=$0 }
    /KKHKHKH/ { print t; print }' file.txt
```

If the file always contains `test` on the previous line before the match, you could also say

```
grep -B 1 'KKHKHKH' file.txt
```

though this will also produce some output between the matches which you might not want.

If the match is always followed my an empty line, a small adaptation of the Awk script should work to only get the last match in each block:

```
awk '/^test/ { t=$0 }
    /KKHKHKH/ { p=$0 }
    /^$/ && p { print t; print p; t=p="" }
    END { if(p) { print t; print p }}' file.txt
```

The `END` block may be unnecessary if there is certain to be an empty line after the last block, too; but missing the last match in scenarios like this is a common error, and the safeguard is reasonably simple (though I was lazy and produced some duplicated code).

Comment: So the awk command will output:

LKJKLLLKJHKLKLJLJKJJLKJLJLHHLKLJKLHLJLKHLKJLHLHLHLKJHLKHLKHLKJLJLHLKJLJLHLJKLKHLJHJLHLHJLKJJLKHLKHLKHLKHLKJJLJLJLHLKLKJLJLLHJKHLKHLHLJHLJHLJHLJHLHLJLKJLKJLJHHJHKJHKJHKJHKKHKHKH

Multiple times, but doesnt include the test number. Is there a way to just extract the furthest match under each test?

Comment: It does print the test number. Maybe your input file contains DOS control codes or something? Getting the last matching line will certainly be possible but really, you need to edit your question so we can see what the input file really looks like. (Code formatting would work better than quoting.)

Comment: Ah I added a picture to my post under the initial data at the top. Thank you so much, I am pretty sure its the > symbo that is throwing it off. I was having trouble figuring out how to indent paragraphs of string in the editor as it the formatting was killing me, the breakpoints just were not happening.

Comment: Pictures of data are generally worthless.

Answer (score -2):

grep -o 'test.*KKHKHKH' file.txt

Comment: Still comes back with nothing? which is interesting as this should technically span white space too I thought, at least from my tutorials. Thank you though!